# Basis of finite dimensional bornology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space then it is algebraically isomorph to $\mathbb{K}^{(I)} = \bigoplus_{i \in I}\mathbb{K}$. Equipping $\mathbb{K}$ with the canonical bornology (absolute value bounded sets) we define the finite dimensional vector bornology $\mathcal{B}_{fin}$ on $X$ by looking at the direct sum bornology (final bornology with respect to the canonical maps $\iota_i : X_i \to \bigoplus_{i \in I}X_i$ when $(X_i,\mathcal{B}_i)$ are all vector bornologies hence finest vector bornology such that all $\iota_i$ are linear and bounded) on $\mathbb{K}^{(I)}$ with respect to the canonical mappings $\iota_i : \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K}^{(I)}$ and using the isomorphism between $X$ and $\mathbb{K}^{(I)}$. So the finite dimensional vector bornology is the finest vector bornology and is always convex. I showed that the direct sum bornology has
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{B}_{\bigoplus} = \lbrace \bigoplus_{i \in I}B_i | B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i, |\lbrace i \in I | B_i \neq \emptyset \rbrace| < \infty \rbrace
\end{equation*}
as a basis where $(X_i,\mathcal{B}_i)$ are bornological vector spaces (in our case for the finite dimensional vector bornology $X_i = \mathbb{K}$ and $\mathcal{B}_i$ are all the canonical bornology $\mathcal{B}$). This just means that the direct sum bornology is given by
\begin{equation}
\lbrace A \subseteq \bigoplus_{i \in I}X_i |  \exists J,|J| < \infty; B_j \in \mathcal{B}_j,j \in J: A \subseteq \bigoplus_{j \in J}B_j \rbrace
\end{equation}
From this one sees that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{fin} = \lbrace A \subseteq X | \exists J, |J| < \infty; B_j \in \mathcal{B},  j\in J : \varphi(A) \subseteq \bigoplus_{j \in J}B_j \rbrace
\end{equation}
where $\varphi$ is the algebraic isomorphism from $X$ to $\mathbb{K}^{(I)}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is the canonical bornology.
Some authors claim that if given a LCTVS $(X,\mathcal{T})$ then the finite dimensional vector bornology has a specific form namely
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{fin} = \lbrace A \subseteq X | \exists J, |J| < \infty; x_j \in X,j \in J : A \subseteq \mbox{conv}(\lbrace x_j : j \in J\rbrace) \rbrace
\end{equation}
where $\mbox{conv}(\cdot)$ stands for the convex hull.  So the basis has a specific form of convex hulls of finite many elements.

Now my question: Why does the basis of the finite dimensional vector bornology consists of convex hulls of finite many elements in $X$ when $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a LCTVS?

The only thing I know when there is a topology $\mathcal{T}$ given which makes $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a LCTVS is that the von Neumann Bornology $\mathcal{B}$ (a set is bounded if it gets absorbed by every Neighbourhood of $0$) is a convex vector bornology and the finite dimensional vector bornology being the finest vector bornology must have something to do with this.
But I cannot see how this is related to the basis of the finite dimensional vector bornology consisting of sets of the form $\mbox{conv}(\lbrace x_j : j \in J\rbrace)$ for finitely many $x_j \in X$.

Comment: On finite dimensional spaces there is only one Hausdorff vector space topology. Isn't your question then, why every bounded subset of $\mathbb K^n$ is contained in the convex hull of some finite set? That's easy.